# How to save webcontent and images in objective-c iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

Requirement of my project is, if device have internet connectivity, need to get the content from server and show it in UIWebview, other wise get conent from local. For that i have stored xml content to sqlite, i don't know how should i save the images which comes in HTML NODE  to local. can any one help me out.

Thanks

sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting url of the image. You can create the documentdirectory and save the images in that directory. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code from this url you can find Apple sample code regarding url connection